# appending code to create multiple random moving sprites - python tkinter

Tags: python

Below is the code I am trying to get working, i currently have it creating the sprites although once the second sprite is created the movement for the first is stopped.

Say there are 2 sprites both of them should be moving individually, completely random from each other.

The code creates a new sprite every 3 seconds(for testing purposes once the code is working it will be set to 10 seconds)

```
class enemymove(object):
    def create():
        global enemy, radiusenemy, xenemy, yenemy
        amount = 0
        enemy = list()
        xenemy = list()
        yenemy = list()
        enemypositionx = list()
        enemypositiony = list()
        lastop = len(enemy)
        enemy.append(amount)
        xenemy.append(amount)
        yenemy.append(amount)
        enemypositionx.append(amount)
        enemypositiony.append(amount)
        amount = amount + 1
        radiusenemy = 12.5
        enemypositionx[lastop] = random.uniform(12.5, resX-12.5)
        enemypositiony[lastop] = random.uniform(12.5, resY-12.5)
        print(lastop)
        enemy[lastop] = canvas.create_oval((enemypositionx[lastop]) + radiusenemy ,(enemypositiony[lastop]) - radiusenemy ,(enemypositionx[lastop]) - radiusenemy ,(enemypositiony[lastop]) + radiusenemy, fill="black", outline="black")
        xenemy[lastop] = (canvas.coords(enemy[lastop])[2])  - 12.5
        yenemy[lastop] = (canvas.coords(enemy[lastop])[3])  - 12.5
        Thread(target = spawntime.timer).start()
        enemymove.movement(lastop);

    def movement(lastop):
        global timer
        timer = random.randint(150,3000)
        count = random.randint(1, 4)
        print(count)
        if count == 1:
            enemymove.up(lastop);
        if count == 2:
            enemymove.downward(lastop);
        if count == 3:
            enemymove.rightran(lastop);
        if count == 4:
            enemymove.leftran(lastop);

    def up(lastop):
        global xenemy, yenemy
        print ("forward")
        yenemy[lastop] = (canvas.coords(enemy[lastop])[1])
        canvas.coords(enemy[lastop], xenemy[lastop] + radiusenemy, yenemy[lastop] + radiusenemy, xenemy[lastop] - radiusenemy, yenemy[lastop] - radiusenemy)
        print(yenemy)
        print(xenemy)
        canvas.after(timer, enemymove.movement, lastop)

    def downward(lastop):
        global xenemy, yenemy
        print("back")
        yenemy[lastop] = (canvas.coords(enemy[lastop])[3]) 
        canvas.coords(enemy[lastop], xenemy[lastop] - radiusenemy, yenemy[lastop] + radiusenemy, xenemy[lastop] + radiusenemy, yenemy[lastop] - radiusenemy)
        print(yenemy)
        print(xenemy)
        canvas.after(timer, enemymove.movement, lastop)

    def rightran(lastop):
        global xenemy, yenemy
        print("right")
        xenemy[lastop] = (canvas.coords(enemy[lastop])[2]) 
           canvas.coords(enemy[lastop], xenemy[lastop] - radiusenemy, yenemy[lastop] - radiusenemy, xenemy[lastop] + radiusenemy, yenemy[lastop] + radiusenemy)
        print(yenemy)
        print(xenemy)
        canvas.after(timer, enemymove.movement, lastop)

    def leftran(lastop):
        global xenemy, yenemy
        print("left")
        xenemy[lastop] = (canvas.coords(enemy[lastop])[0])
        canvas.coords(enemy[lastop], xenemy[lastop] - radiusenemy, yenemy[lastop] - radiusenemy, xenemy[lastop] + radiusenemy, yenemy[lastop] + radiusenemy)
        print(yenemy)
        print(xenemy)
        canvas.after(timer, enemymove.movement, lastop)

class spawntime():
    def timer():
        global timeset
        timeset = 3
        spawntime.calculation()

    def calculation():
        global timeset
        print ('The count is: ', timeset)
        if timeset <= 0:
            enemymove.create()
        else:
            timeset -= 1
            canvas.after(1000, spawntime.calculation)

    #runs the main code
    def main():
        global root, canvas
        root.title("")
        canvas = Canvas(root, width= resX, height=resY, bg = "white")
        canvas.pack()
        Thread(target = spawntime.timer).start()  
        root.mainloop()

    main()
```

I'm reasonably new to appending, so making multiple different appended sprites move all together is out of my range, and so I am unsure of how to get this to work.

Comment: learn how to use `class` and `self.` (in `class`) in place of `global`

Comment: you can use `enemy[-1]` to get last element on the list - you don't need `lastop`.

Comment: you mean everywhere? and yeah i need to learn how to use it better haha

Comment: but i just need to know how to get all the sprites moving rather than only one being able to move

Comment: I tried to understand your classes but I think you make it too complicated. I can only say - if you need  something to do with all elements on the list then use `for` loop - like `for number in range(amount): enemy[number] = ...`

Comment: btw: I think you don't need `Thread` if you use `canvas.after` (or rather `root.after`).

Comment: that timer is a random number for the time between movement of the sprites. the def timer is the time between spawns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your code so I create own version. Now every enemy moves after random time. After random time I add new enemy

I keep enemies on list but I don't need this list.

```
import random

import tkinter as tk

# --- constants --- # UPPERCASE name

RES_X = 800
RES_Y = 600

# --- classes --- # CamelCase name 

class Enemies(object):

    def __init__(self, canvas):

        # access to canvas
        self.canvas = canvas

        # started amount of enemies
        self.amount = 5

        # list for all enemies
        self.enemies = list()

        # create enemies
        for _ in range(self.amount):
            self.create_one_enemy()

    def create_one_enemy(self):
        radius = 12.5 # random

        x = random.uniform(radius, RES_X-radius)
        y = random.uniform(radius, RES_Y-radius)

        oval = self.canvas.create_oval(x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius, fill="black", outline="black")

        # one enemy
        enemy = [x, y, radius, oval]

        # apped to list - but I don't need this list 
        self.enemies.append(enemy)

        # move this enemy after random time
        random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
        root.after(random_time, self.move_one_enemy, enemy)

    def move_one_enemy(self, enemy):

        #print('moving:', enemy)

        # get old values
        x, y, radius, oval = enemy

        direction = random.randint(1,4)

        if direction == 1: # up
            y -= radius
        elif direction == 2: # down
            y += radius
        elif direction == 3: # left
            x -= radius
        elif direction == 4: # right
            x += radius

        self.canvas.coords(oval, x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius)

        # remember new values
        enemy[0] = x
        enemy[1] = y

        # move this enemy after random time
        random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
        root.after(random_time, self.move_one_enemy, enemy)

# --- functions --- # lower_case name 

def add_new_enemy():

    enemies.create_one_enemy()

    # add next enemy after random time
    timer = random.randint(150, 3000)
    root.after(random_time, add_new_enemy)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=RES_X, height=RES_Y, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

# create enemies and move it using `root.after`
enemies = Enemies(canvas)

# add new enemy after random time
random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
root.after(random_time, add_new_enemy)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** but rather I would create class `Enemy` for single enemy and then list `enemies` to keep all `Enemy` instances.

```
import random

import tkinter as tk

# --- constants --- # UPPERCASE name

RES_X = 800
RES_Y = 600

# --- classes --- # CamelCase name 

class Enemy(object):
    '''single enemy'''

    def __init__(self, canvas):

        # access to canvas
        self.canvas = canvas

        self.radius = 12.5 # random

        self.color = random.choice( ('black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow') )

        self.x = random.uniform(self.radius, RES_X-self.radius)
        self.y = random.uniform(self.radius, RES_Y-self.radius)

        self.x1 = self.x-self.radius
        self.y1 = self.y-self.radius

        self.x2 = self.x+self.radius
        self.y2 = self.y+self.radius

        self.oval = self.canvas.create_oval(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill=self.color, outline=self.color)

        self.moving = True

        self.start()


    def start(self):
        '''start moving'''

        self.moving = True

        # move this enemy after random time
        random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
        root.after(random_time, self.move)


    def stop(self):
        '''stop moving'''

        self.moving = False


    def move(self):

        if self.moving: # to stop root.after

            direction = random.randint(1,4)

            if direction == 1: # up
                self.y -= self.radius
                self.y1 -= self.radius
                self.y2 -= self.radius
            elif direction == 2: # down
                self.y += self.radius
                self.y1 += self.radius
                self.y2 += self.radius
            elif direction == 3: # left
                self.x -= self.radius
                self.x1 -= self.radius
                self.x2 -= self.radius
            elif direction == 4: # right
                self.x += self.radius
                self.x1 += self.radius
                self.x2 += self.radius

            self.canvas.coords(self.oval, self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)
            # move this enemy after random time
            random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
            root.after(random_time, self.move)

# --- functions --- # lower_case name 

def add_new_enemy():

    enemies.append(Enemy(canvas))

    # add next enemy after random time
    timer = random.randint(150, 3000)
    root.after(random_time, add_new_enemy)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=RES_X, height=RES_Y, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

# 5 enemies at the beginning
enemies = list()

for _ in range(5):
    enemies.append(Enemy(canvas))

# add new enemy after random time
random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
root.after(random_time, add_new_enemy)

root.mainloop()
```

And now you can use list to stop/start enemies

```
for one_enemy in enemies:
    one_enemy.stop()
```

or check some information

```
for one_enemy in enemies:
    print("x:", one_enemy.x)
    print("y:", one_enemy.y)
```

btw: and then you can create `EnemiesGroup` class

---

**EDIT:** `EnemiesGroup` and buttons to control group

```
import random

import tkinter as tk

# --- constants --- # UPPERCASE name

RES_X = 800
RES_Y = 600

# --- classes --- # CamelCase name 

class Enemy(object):
    '''single enemy'''

    def __init__(self, canvas):

        # access to canvas
        self.canvas = canvas

        self.radius = 12.5 # random

        self.color = random.choice( ('black', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow') )

        self.x = random.uniform(self.radius, RES_X-self.radius)
        self.y = random.uniform(self.radius, RES_Y-self.radius)

        self.x1 = self.x-self.radius
        self.y1 = self.y-self.radius

        self.x2 = self.x+self.radius
        self.y2 = self.y+self.radius

        self.oval = self.canvas.create_oval(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill=self.color, outline=self.color)

        self.moving = True

        self.start()


    def start(self):
        '''start moving'''

        self.moving = True

        # move this enemy after random time
        random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
        root.after(random_time, self.move)


    def stop(self):
        '''stop moving'''

        self.moving = False


    def move(self):

        if self.moving: # to stop root.after
            direction = random.randint(1,4)

            if direction == 1: # up
                self.y -= self.radius
                self.y1 -= self.radius
                self.y2 -= self.radius
            elif direction == 2: # down
                self.y += self.radius
                self.y1 += self.radius
                self.y2 += self.radius
            elif direction == 3: # left
                self.x -= self.radius
                self.x1 -= self.radius
                self.x2 -= self.radius
            elif direction == 4: # right
                self.x += self.radius
                self.x1 += self.radius
                self.x2 += self.radius

            self.canvas.coords(self.oval, self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)

            # move this enemy after random time
            random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
            root.after(random_time, self.move)

class EnemiesGroup(object):

    def __init__(self, canvas):

        self.canvas = canvas

        self.enemies = list()

        self.moving = True


    def add_new_enemy(self):

        # can be only 5 enemies 
        if len(self.enemies) < 5:
            e = Enemy(self.canvas)

            # stop new enemy if all enemies are stoped
            e.moving = self.moving

            self.enemies.append(e)
        else:
            print("You have 5 enemies - I can't add more.")

    def stop_all_enemies(self):
        for e in self.enemies:
            e.stop()

        # all enemies are stoped
        self.moving = False


    def start_all_enemies(self):
        for e in self.enemies:
            e.start()

        # all enemies are moving
        self.moving = True

# --- functions --- # lower_case name

def add_new_enemy():

    enemies_group.add_new_enemy()

    # add next enemy after random time
    timer = random.randint(150, 3000)
    root.after(random_time, add_new_enemy)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=RES_X, height=RES_Y, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

# enemies

enemies_group = EnemiesGroup(canvas)

for _ in range(5):
    enemies_group.add_new_enemy()

# add new enemy after random time
random_time = random.randint(150, 3000)
root.after(random_time, add_new_enemy)

# buttons to control all enemies

button_stop = tk.Button(root, text='STOP', command=enemies_group.stop_all_enemies)
button_stop.pack()

button_start = tk.Button(root, text='START', command=enemies_group.start_all_enemies)
button_start.pack()

button_add = tk.Button(root, text='ADD NEW ENEMY', command=enemies_group.add_new_enemy)
button_add.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** removing enemy by clicking oval.

In `add_new_enemy` I bind to `oval` event `<Button-1>` and function `clicked` (with enemy object).

Function `clicked` removes `oval` from `canvas` and removes `enemy` from `enemies group`.

```
class EnemiesGroup(object):

    # ... other functions ...    

    def clicked(self, event, enemy):
        print('clicked:', enemy),

        # remove oval from canvas        
        self.canvas.delete(enemy.oval)

        # remove enemy from list
        self.enemies.remove(enemy)

        # create new enemy after 10s
        root.after(10000, self.add_new_enemy)


    def add_new_enemy(self):

        # can be only 5 enemies 
        if len(self.enemies) < 5:
            print('create new enemy')
            e = Enemy(self.canvas)

            # stop new enemy if all enemies are stoped
            e.moving = self.moving

            # bind mouse button to enemy
            self.canvas.tag_bind(e.oval, '<Button-1>', lambda event:self.clicked(event, e))

            self.enemies.append(e)
        else:
            print("You have 5 enemies - I can't add more.")


    # ... other functions ...
```

Comment: thanks haha ill try work through that slowly, does what i want with the spawning of new circles although they are supposed to spawn every 10 seconds rather than it being random. and having them all move together is good too. thanks!

Comment: i have one more question about this, what variable is the list. so say i wanted to limit it to 5 of the sprites what variable would i have to limit?

Comment: in first version list is inside `Enemies` class available as `self.enemies` and available outside as `enemies.enemies` (instance_name.property_in_instance). In second version (with `Enemy` class) list is global variable `enemies`. In third version list is inside `EnemiesGroup` avaliable as `self.enemies` and available outside as `enemies_group.enemies`. To limit it to 5 you have to check size (length) before you add element to the list `if len(enemies_group.enemies) < 5: enemies_group.enemies.append(new_sprite)`. You could create method `add` (in class) with this code.

Comment: im using the last version and it doesnt seem to pick up enemies

Comment: In last version I add all enemies using method `enemies_group.add_new_enemy` so I modify this method in class `EnemiesGroup` to limit enemies to 5.

Comment: it doesnt seem to want to stop on my version of the code haha, but when i  copy yours into another file and run it it works fine...

Comment: okay got it working just had to change some stuff around as i think it was calling the function from other places haha

Comment: how do i go about removing a item from the canvas and the list? so that it can be reused. say one is clicked it needs to be removed and then respawn 10 seconds later. how do i go about removing the one that was clicked specifically?

Comment: you have to `bind` to `enemy.oval`  event `<Button-1>` with function which removes `enemy.oval` from `canvas`, remove `enemy` from `enemies_group.enemies` and run `after(10000, enemies_group.add_new_enemy)` to respawn new enemy after 10s.